# Почему при создании div блока не могу удалить его по id? javascript, js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Через `ajax` добавляю блок `div` через `after`:

`$('#ajax-service').after('<div id="#ajax-service-list" name="#ajax-service-list">'+(response.is_taken)+'</div>')`

почему при новом запросе, не удаляются старые блоки по `$('#ajax-service-list').remove();`?

**html**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // catch the form's submit event
            $('#ajax-service').keyup(function () {
                // create an AJAX call
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                    url: "{% url 'ajax_request' %}",
                    // on success
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.is_taken) {
                            $('#ajax-response').remove();
                            $('#ajax-service').after('<div id="#ajax-response">'+(response.is_taken)+'</div>')
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#ajax-service').after('<div id="#ajax-response">Нет совпадений</div>')
                            $('#ajax-response').remove();

                        }
                    },
                    // on error
                    error: function (response) {
                        // alert the error if any error occured
                        console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
```

то есть получается такая каша
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значение атрибута id указывайте без решётки в начале (`#ajax-response`) - это-же ведь не селектор jQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('.ajax-response').remove();
 $('#ajax-service').after('<div class="ajax-response">' + response.is_taken + '</div>')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]